# How to read/import css/less from other sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sbt project A which depends on an other sbt project B, the projects A and B have the same structure.

```
--> build.sbt

--> src

      --> main 
    
         --> resources / assets / styles/*.less

         --> resources / index.html
```

I'm in A, in it index.html, i can import the lesses using :

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../assets/styles/lessA.less" />`

How can i import lessB.less which exists in project B ?

Comment: Which framework are you using for rendering the pages?

Comment: @Gael i dont use framework for rendering

Comment: Then which server is serving your pages? Play Framework?

Comment: You can look into what is called "webjar" and search how your framework would support it